# jQuery content scroller

Tags: jquery, html

"Content scroll" when we hover on "up" "down" buttons 
Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/s5mgX/1657/

My questions is -  I need to "Content scroll" when also mouse scrolling on that content area ?

```
var step = 25;
var scrolling = false;

// Wire up events for the 'scrollUp' link:
$("#scrollUp").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Animates the scrollTop property by the specified
    // step.
    $("#content").animate({
        scrollTop: "-=" + step + "px"
    });
}).bind("mouseover", function(event) {
    scrolling = true;
    scrollContent("up");
}).bind("mouseout", function(event) {
    scrolling = false;
});


$("#scrollDown").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#content").animate({
        scrollTop: "+=" + step + "px"
    });
}).bind("mouseover", function(event) {
    scrolling = true;
    scrollContent("down");
}).bind("mouseout", function(event) {
    scrolling = false;
});

function scrollContent(direction) {
    var amount = (direction === "up" ? "-=1px" : "+=1px");
    $("#content").animate({
        scrollTop: amount
    }, 1, function() {
        if (scrolling) {
            scrollContent(direction);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the `jQuery Mousewheel` plugin.

You can download it here:

https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel

And just add a reference after the regular `jQuery` libray on the page header.